# Ajax callback dunce

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I am having difficulty understanding how to implement a callback function.  I've search around alot and found a lot of material on the subject but nothing that I've been able to implement in my jQuery code.

Can someone please edit my code here so I can copy it back into my test page to see exactly what I need to do?

**What I need**

First, declare a variable and give it a value.
Second Execute my Ajax call and reference that variable.  Sounds easy but I don't get it.  Here's my code example if you would be so kind to help me.

```
var myName = 'Ann';

$.ajax(
{
    type:       "post",
    url:        "URL",
    cache:      false,
    dataType:   "json",
    data: 
    {
        xxxxxx: xxxxxxxxx
    },
    success: function(objResponse) 
    {
        //How can I do this????
        alert(myName);
    }
});
```

Comment: what errors are you getting, if any? is the response being cached perhaps?

Comment: That should work. If it isn't, that means either you are getting data that is of the wrong type, or the server is returning an error status code. What is the server returning?

Comment: I declared myName immediately above the Ajax call.  For some reason, when I copy/pasted into this editor, it put the variable declaration outside of the gray area.

Comment: I've been doing this for a bit now and it no matter what I do, I cannot reference a variable from within a success method.

Comment: maybe your response is not valid JSON, or the MIME type on the server is wrong. use this to check validity of the response: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Are you trying to reference a variable you are getting from the server in response to the ajax? Or just an unchanged variable

Comment: Chimoo, I get an 'undefined' error.

Comment: Chimoo, I am referencing a variable that is set local to the function that my Ajax call is in. So, my function is called saveStep and within it, I set some variables and then do the Ajax call.  From within the Ajax call, I cannot reference the variables I set just before it.

Comment: So the alert statement is actually run?

Comment: Yes.  But is says 'undefined'

Comment: try removing the "var" before setting the variable so just use myName = "Ann";

Comment: My apologies to all.  I discovered a logic burp in my code.  Problem solved.

Comment: However, I still don't really understand the concept of callbacks.  I'll keep reading.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

seems like this should work? works for me every day.

```
var myName = 'lol';
$.ajax({
        type:       "post",
        url:        "URL",
        cache:      false,
        dataType:   "json",
        data: {
                xxxxxx: xxxxxxxxx
              },

        success: function(objResponse) 
        {
            //How can I do this????
            alert(myName);
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) { alert("Error: \n\nreadyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status + "\nresponseText: " + xhr.responseText, 'nosave'); }
    });
```

if the alert isn't firing, you should add an error to this, like i did above.

you should look into developing with firebug, you will be able to see all ajax calls you make.

Comment: Or use the Developer Tools built into Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you to understand it a bit better;)
Your **ajaxprocess.html** looks like this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
  <meta name="author" content=""/>
  <meta name="description" content=""/>
  <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  *{margin:0px;padding:0px}
  .content{
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:30px;
  }
  .button{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100px;
  hight:100px;
  display:block;
  }
  .strong{
  display:none;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var myName = 'John';
   var myImage = $('<img src = "path to your image"/>');
   $('.button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url:'load.html',
     success:function(data){     
     $('.content').html(data);
     //$(".images").append(myImage);//Uncomment this if you want to insert Your image...
     $('.strong').fadeIn(2000,function(){
     alert(data);//We shall alert our data after the DATA
     alert(myName);//is Faded IN...
     });         

     },error:function (xhr){
     var msg ="Sorry there was an error:";
                alert(msg+" "+xhr.statusText+" "+xhr.status);

            }    
    });
});
});
```

Your **load.html** looks like this: 
Now all you need to is to **copy** those two files on your server and scrutinize how **ajaxprocess.html** looks like... Hope This helps:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
 <meta name="author" content=""/>
 <meta name="description" content=""/>
 <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
 *{margin:0px;padding:0px}
 </style>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <strong class="strong">This was loaded OK!!!<span class="images"></span></strong>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the invokedata of ajax. This will let you pass variables to the success function.

Here a example in this link: http://weboutofthebox.com/en-GB/28/Article/Ajaxinvokedataparameter

I don't know if you are using firebug, but if not, use firefox install firebug and view what is happening.